# connect to websites sql database and show web content on android

Tags: android, sql, database

My dad wants me to make a android and iPhone app for his website , I'm still learning java and am doing the android one first. What i am looking for is how to connect to his sql database so i could have them logon from within the app and then show website content , But not in a webview how would this work ? Could you point me to some tutorials?

Answer (score 4):

You should create a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) and consume a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) API or some other data interchange format.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make the database accable from the internet! This is very dangerous if you are not very familar with server configuration. Transmit instat the data thrue http. E.g. a PHP script in a JSON container.

Look for the [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) function and the [json-encode](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) function.

See also this simple and insecure example:

```php
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sometable");

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

$rows=array();
// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[]=$row;
}

// output in JSON format
echo(json_encode($rows));

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: Okay that php script makes sense i know a little bit of php but how would i use that in a android app?

Comment: You have to download the file and to decode the file. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578441/example-of-how-to-download-json-from-server) to get an idea how to do this. Also remember that you need the internet permission.