# How can I reach the JSONObject stored on Tomcat server via android?

Tags: android, json, jersey, httpclient, http-get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example of how to download JSON from server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578441/example-of-how-to-download-json-from-server)

I've read quite a few tutorials but it's still not clear how it works. This is the server side code:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public JSONObject respondAsReady() throws JSONException {
           JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
           json.put("email", "email");
           json.put("szam", 5);
           json.put("boolean", true);
           return json;
           }
```

Server-side code:

```
public class GetJson extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getjson_layout);
    Button get=(Button)findViewById(R.id.get);

    get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          getMethod();
        }
      });   
    }}
```

What's the easiest way to code the getMethod function? I don't need neither AsyncTask, nor any extras, just to get back the JSONObject written in @GET through the server
For example, print to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to consume a REST web service

`String url = "getserviceurl";` // such as `http://yourhost:8080/rest-ws/resources/admin/getCities`

```
        String responseString ="";

        final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        final DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        final HttpEntity reponseEntity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = reponseEntity.getContent();

        if (inputStream != null)
        {
            responseString = getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);

        }



// This will convert your inputStream into a String
protected String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    String responseString = null;
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;

    while ((ch = inputStream.read()) != -1)
    {
        stringBuilder.append((char) ch);
    }

    responseString = stringBuilder.toString();

    return responseString;
}
```